# Describe and illustrate the ball $B_1(0,0) $.

Tags: metric-spaces

On  $\mathbb{R}^2$  we have a metric defined by $d(x,y)=|x_1- y_1|+ |x_2- y_2|$. Describe and illustrate $B_1(0,0)$, the ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin $(0,0)$.

SOLUTION
By definition  $B_1(0, 0)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :  |x-0|+|y-0|<1\}$
Since the ball is at the origin and it has the radius one, then I find that it is the set of all points within the rectangle having the corner points $(0, 1)$, $(1, 0)$, $(0,-1)$, and $(-1,0)$
Is my idea correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is correct.

Though it wasn't asked for in your problem, a justification of your answer would be edifying:

The open unit ball is by definition
$$
  B(0,1)=\bigl\{\, (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\bigl|\,|x|+|y|<1\,\bigr\}.
$$ 
Towards determining geometrically what $B(0,1)$ is, let's consider cases:

Let's find the portion of $B(0,1)$ in the first quadrant of the Euclidian plane.
If $(x,y)$ is in the first quadrant of the Euclidian plane, then $(x,y)\in B(0,1)$ if and only if $x+y<1$.  If you sketch the graph of the equation $x+y=1$, you should be able to convince yourself that $Q_1\cap B(0,1)$ is the region depicted below (you want the region in Quadrant 1 with $x+y<1$, this would be the region in Quadrant 1 beneath the graph of the equation $x+y=1$).

[image]

If you consider the other cases according to the other three quadrants, you can establish that $B(0,1)$ is as you described and as depicted below (or, you could use a symmetry argument):

[image]

Note that since $B(0,1)$ is the open unit ball, points on the the boundary of the diamond above are not in $B(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct. This metric is commonly known as the "Manhatten metric", because in Manhattan the *driving* distance from one point to another is roughly the difference in avenues plus the difference in streets (or whatever they call the lanes out there).

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, an open "ball" is "actually" an open rhombus. Now, this is wrong, of course, since under the manhattan metric a rhombus would be yet another form, so strictly speaking I should say that an open ball under the manhattan metric is an open rhombus under the euclidean metric.