# Open balls appearance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We know that with the euclidean metric the open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are circles without the frontier, of course.

My question is if there exist a known metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the open balls have the appearance as triangles or hexagons?

Thank you for the support.

Comment: Why don't you try $d \left( \left( x_1, y_1 \right), \left( x_2, y_2 \right) \right) = \left| x_1 - x_2 \right| + \left| y_1 - y_2 \right|$ or $d \left( \left( x_1, y_1 \right), \left( x_2, y_2 \right) \right) = \max \left\lbrace \left| x_1 - x_2 \right|, \left| y_1 - y_2 \right| \right\rbrace$? Try making open balls of radius $1$ centered at origin with these metrics. You will find your answer.

Comment: Open balls in the taxicab metric are squares, see for example [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131746/describe-and-illustrate-the-ball-b-10-0).

Comment: You may refer https://people.uwec.edu/mbirika/M316_Notes/Metric_Spaces_Open_Balls_and_Limit_Points.pdf for more information

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want a metric which induces the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If you want that the metric is induced by a **norm**, then you can find an answer here: [Norm induced by convex, open, symmetric, bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1495726) . Note that any open norm-ball centered at $0$ must be  bounded, open, convex and centre symmetric (for bounded recall that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent). This excludes triangles, but allows hexagons.

Edited:

Let $H$ be an open hexagon with centre $0$ and vertices lying on the unit circle. It is  bounded, open, convex and centre symmetric. As in the above link define
$$\|x\|_{hex} = \inf \{k>0 : x/k \in H  \} .$$
This is a norm such that $H = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\|_{hex} < 1 \}$. Note that
$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\|_{hex} < r \} = r H ,$$
the latter being defined as $r H  = \{r h \mid h \in H \}$. This is again an open hexagon stretched by the factor $r$. Our norm induces the metric
$$d_{hex}(x,y) =  \|x - y\|_{hex} .$$
Then 
$$B_{hex}(x;r) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid d_{hex}(x,y) < r \} = x  + B_{hex}(0;r) = x +r H$$
which is an open hexagon with centre $x$.

The same construction can be performed for any bounded, open, convex and centre symmetric set $A$. Then all open balls with respect to the metric $d_A$ are copies of some $rA$ (which is obtained by stretching $A$).

Comment: Well, and my question is there exist (or how you can construct) a metric such that the open balls be hexagons?

Comment: I edited my answer.